# Allow retagging of locked posts

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, locked

It would be nice to be able to retag locked questions (migrated questions in particular), without being able to edit the actual body. Kinda like a user with more than 500 rep and less than 2000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flag them for moderator attention, if a locked question has a tag that needs removing.

Answer (score 5):

It shouldn't happen so often that the community needs to take care of it - probably best flagged for mod attention with a note on the retagging.

Answer (score 1):

The question might have been locked because of a tag tug-of-war, so maybe not feasible.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a single instance where this happened in the entire history of stack overflow, super user or server fault? Thanks!

Comment: @kop - Not off hand, but it has happened a few times over the past year or so. I suggest you read this: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-great-edit-wars/ . Tag battles were part of these wars. For me this is stuff from the deep past and I never kept bookmarks. But just ask any seasoned SO user and you'll get plenty of anecdotal tales.

Comment: @Kev: while I'm sure there have been some (minor) tag wars in the past, I was asking for an example of a post that has been **locked** to prevent changing its tags.

Comment: @kop - It's so long ago, it's been done and dusted and I don't have the time to go back and look through half a million questions. But my point is valid. Posts get locked either because of an edit war or re-tag disagreement amongst other things.

Comment: What I was trying to argue is that only because it may have happened "so long ago" one time it doesn't mean that it's worth the trouble of not being able to retag them. Anyway it could still be done only for migrated question; that was my main concern.

Comment: @kop - didn't mean to sound off-hand there by the way :)... but yeah I guess migrated questions might be candidates for special treatment.